# get fetch the data of last 20 tuesday in aws redshift

Tags: amazon-redshift

I want to find data for the last 20 Tuesday.
I have to write fro getting the desired result as mentioned below.

```
        Date                    value
2020-03-03 01:12:15               5
2020-02-25 07:12:15               13
2020-02-24 08:12:15               1
2020-02-23 09:12:15               32
2020-02-22 10:12:15               7
2020-02-21 11:12:15               43
2020-02-20 12:12:15               7
2020-02-19 13:12:15               1
2020-02-18 14:12:15               31
2020-02-17 15:12:15               14
2020-02-16 15:12:15               2
2020-02-15 15:12:15               14
2020-02-14 14:12:15               31
2020-02-13 15:12:15               11
2020-02-12 15:12:15               2
2020-02-11 15:12:15               14
2020-02-10 15:12:15               12
```

and so one

My desired output is

```
        Date                    value
2020-02-24 01:12:15               1
2020-02-17 07:12:15               14
2020-02-10 14:12:15               12
and so on
```

Comment: Why are the times different in your output than in the table?

Answer (score 0):

You could probably use:

```sql
WHERE
  DATE_PART(dow, date_field) = 2
  AND date_field >= CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL '140 DAYS'
```

See: [DATE_PART Function - Amazon Redshift](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_DATE_PART_function.html)